# Implementing routing with Spray clients inside an ActorSystem

Tags: scala, routes, akka, actor, spray

I've a Spray client that is used to invoke a REST web service. Currently I'm creating an instance of this client (using `new GeoSprayWebClient`) [see code below] and reusing it inside my actors to make the REST requests. However, a single instance of the service is not able to handle all the load. Therefore, I want to introduce replicas of the REST service.

I'm new to Spray and still trying to learn the fundamentals. My questions are

1) I know Spray internally uses Akka actors. In this particular case can I get an `ActorRef` for client instances so that I can create multiple client ActorRefs and use them to create an Akka router. 
2) Does the Spray client API provide any kind of routing capability that will support my use case?

```
 import akka.actor.ActorSystem
 import spray.client.pipelining._
 import spray.http._
 import scala.concurrent.Future


trait GeoWebClient {
  def get(url: String, params: Map[String, String]): Future[String]
}

class GeoSprayWebClient(implicit system: ActorSystem) extends GeoWebClient {

  import system.dispatcher

  // create a function from HttpRequest to a Future of HttpResponse
  val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] = sendReceive

  // create a function to send a GET request and receive a string response
  def get(path: String, params: Map[String, String]): Future[String] = {
    val uri = Uri(path) withQuery params
    val request = Get(uri)
    val futureResponse = pipeline(request)
    futureResponse.map(_.entity.asString)
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd use the spray-can client API as described here: http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.1/spray-can/http-client/host-level/#starting-an-httphostconnector You can create several host-connectors (usually for the different hosts you want to distribute over) for which you then get the ActorRef and put them behind an Akka Router.

Comment: @jrudolph -if you can put this as an answer instead of a comment I will accept this as an answer. I was able to solve my problem using this link. I'll also post the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.1/spray-can/http-client/host-level/#starting-an-httphostconnector) I was able to get the `ActorRef`

```
def createHttpRESTClient(host: String, port: Int): ActorRef = {

      // execution context for future transformations below
      import system.dispatcher
      implicit val timeout: Timeout = 10 seconds

      val ref: Future[ActorRef] = for {
        Http.HostConnectorInfo(hostConnector: ActorRef, _) <- IO(Http) ? Http.HostConnectorSetup(host, port)
      }
      yield {
        hostConnector
      }
      //FIXME - TODO fix this it's really bad. However, We are going to create this only once when we create the actor, so I guess it's okay for now.
      Await.result(ref, 10 seconds)
    }
```

And this is how I'm sending the request and getting a response from the service using the ActorRef.

```
  def sendReq(text: String): Future[String] = {
    import spray.http._
    val params = Map(("key" -> text))
    val uri = Uri("/myservice") withQuery params
    val request = Get(uri)
    //send GET request using the "ask" pattern; the timeout
    //TODO - not sure if we can use tell instead of ask here ? 
    val response: Future[HttpResponse] = restSvrActorRef.ask(request).mapTo[HttpResponse]
    log.debug(s"done with sending a request to the REST service")
    response.map(_.entity.asString)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. implement WebClientActor which invokes GeoSprayWebClient to do your work.
2. create a router as the spray handler:

val handler = context.actorOf(
Props[WebClientActor].withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(5)), name = "handlerRouter")

1. send request message to the handler

In this way, we have 5 client instance to do request.

I'm also new to spray, not sure it's for your purpose or not. just for your information.

cheers~!